# How to display Foreign Key with multiple model properties in MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, twitter-bootstrap-3

let's say I have

Customer Model:

```
ID
UserName
Password
LastName
FirstName
City
Street
BuildingNumber
...
```

ServiceCall Model:

```
ID
CustomerID
....
```

In my application every person in the building can open a service call using the building UserName and Password.
In addition to this option they can also call to the company's office and ask the secretary to open a service call for them.
I want to allow the secretary to search the client by a full address, since the customer may not remember his ID,UserName...and so.
I thought to add search button which will open a bootstrap modal with customer search...

what is the best way to implement a pop up that will include search option to another model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is for the modal

```
<div id="form-content" class="modal hide fade in" style="display: none;">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
        <h3>Send me a message</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <form class="contact" name="contact">
            <label class="label" for="name">Name</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="name" class="input-xlarge"><br>
            <label class="label" for="email">E-mail</label><br>
            <input type="email" name="email" class="input-xlarge"><br>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Search" id="submit">
        <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="thanks"><p><a data-toggle="modal" href="#form-content" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Click me to open search</a></p></div>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input#submit").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "process.php", //process to mail
            data: $('form.contact').serialize(),
            success: function(msg){
                $("#thanks").html(msg) //hide button and show thank you
                $("#form-content").modal('hide'); //hide popup  
            },
            error: function(){
                alert("failure");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Then you just have to make the ajax call to server and return to close modla and show results or replace the modal's content by the returned persons.

Comment: Thank you for your comment i will try to clarify my question.